# Default value for array destruction operation in PHP 7.1

Tags: php-7, php-7.1

Is there any way to set a default value for a destructed array that doesn't have the specified index?

Similar to destructing an object in ES6, where if the passed object doesn't have the property (in the following example, the `name` prop), it will have a default value:

```
const ({name = '', age}) => {
};
```

I'm currently destroying an array like the following:

```
// Inside my class
public function __construct(array $props) {
    [ 'id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name ] = $props;
}
```

However, I want the `'id'` to be optional, so that `$this->id` can pick up `0` as a default value when no `'id'` is passed.

Comment: You cannot assign to an array `[ 'id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name ]`. You can only assign values to variables.

Comment: I'm not assigning values to the array, I'm **destructing** the array assigning it's values to my class properties

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php

class Ciao
{
    private $id = 666;

    public function __construct(array $props) {
        $props['id'] = $props['id'] ?? 666;
        [ 'id' => $this->id, 'name' => $this->name ] = $props;
    }
}


$ciao = new Ciao([
    'id' => 42,
    'name' => 'ciao',
]);
// $ciao::$id == 42


$ciao = new Ciao([
    'name' => 'ciao',
]);
// $ciao::$id == 666
```

Comment: It's the other way around, I'm **destructing** an array, not constructing

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco thank you. I discovered new way to use arrays ... Thank you very much!!